# Exclude<T, U> producing different results than conditional type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Just for convenience, here's the implementation of `Exclude<T, U>`

```
type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;
```

Now, consider the following:

```
type T1 = 'dog' | 'cat';
type T2 = 'dog' | 'cat' | 'fish';

type T3 = T1 extends T2 ? never : T1; // T3 = never
type T4 = T2 extends T1 ? never : T2; // T4 = "dog" | "cat" | "fish"

type T5 = Exclude<T1, T2>; // T5 = never
type T6 = Exclude<T2, T1>; // T6 = "fish"

type MyExclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;

type T7 = MyExclude<T1, T2>; // T7 = never
type T8 = MyExclude<T2, T1>; // T8 = "fish"
```

My question is, why is `T4` different than `T6` and `T8`? Why does checking if `T2` directly extends `T1` produce different results than checking if type parameter `T` extends `U`

Comment: Look at the answer to the other question; the difference is that `Exclude` is a distributive conditional type, while your version is not.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!